# Why can't instancetype get property with dot syntax? Is instancetype sometimes id type?

Tags: objective-c

```
    @interface TestInstancetypeObject : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *testString;

    + (instancetype)shareInstance;

    + (NSString *)getString;

    @end

    @implementation TestInstancetypeObject

    + (instancetype)shareInstance {
        static TestInstancetypeObject *instance;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            instance = [[TestInstancetypeObject alloc] init];
        });
        return instance;
    }

    + (NSString *)getString {
        NSString *string0 = [[self shareInstance] testString];
        NSString *string1 = [TestInstancetypeObject shareInstance].testString;
        NSString *string3 = [self shareInstance].testString;//error:: Property 'testString' not found on object of type 'id'

        return string0;
    }

    @end
```

When I try to get a property through [self shareInstance].propertyName in a class method,I get an error: Property 'xxx' not found on object of type 'id'.But [[self shareInstance] propertyName] is successful.Why is [self shareInstance].propertyName wrong?

Comment: Given the code you've shown, what `-init` method do you think is called in `instance = [[TestInstancetypeObject alloc] init]`, and what is the type returned by that method?

Comment: Init method is called by NSObject, the type returned by init method is instancetype.

Comment: `self` just have type `Class` and `instancetype` from it gives `id`